# Python: How to kill or sleep a process if a certain condition met?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-multiprocessing

I have built a scraper that keeps running in infinite loop. It is also using a pool of proxies on 10+ AWS machines. I want to make it like if a single IP hits X times then it should not be hit again, so far so good as I am using MySQL for the purpose. The issue is, what if ALL proxies finished quota, how can I make it sleep or delay and get a new life in new day. Right now I did following but eventually it terminates entire program:

```
def parse():
  if random_proxy == '': # ALL Proxies finished quota for the day
     raise Exception('Proxy Not Found')
   r = session.get(u, headers=headers, proxies={'https': proxy_url})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    idx = 0
    exception_string = ''
    POOL_COUNT = 50
  try:
    if conn is not None:
        links = get_links(conn, POOL_COUNT)
        if conn.open:
          conn.close()
           with Pool(POOL_COUNT) as p:
             result = p.map(parse, links)
except Exception as ex:
        print('Main program exception')
```

Comment: Read about [Synchronization primitives](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-primitives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way to deal with your issue:

```
SLEEP_INTERVAL = 300  # 5 minutes

def parse():
    random_proxy = get_random_proxy()

    while not random_proxy:
        # ALL Proxies finished quota for the day
        time.sleep(SLEEP_INTERVAL)  
        random_proxy = get_random_proxy()

    r = session.get(u, headers=headers, proxies={'https': proxy_url})
```

This will block your workers until a new proxy will be available.